# implicit differentiation, can't find my mistake

Tags: calculus

an equation $y^3+x^3=3xy$
need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

$$(y^3)' = 3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}  $$

$$(x^3)' = 3x^2$$

$$-(3xy)' = -(xy+3x\frac{dy}{dx})$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(3y^2-3x)=xy-3x^2$$

therefore, $$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{xy-3x^2}{3y^2-3x}$$

but it turned out to be a wrong answer.
where is my mistake?
can anyone help?

Comment: Your 3rd differential is wrong.. $ -3xy = -(xy+3x\frac{dy}{dx}) $

Comment: You keep using "$=$". I don't think it means what you think it means. (Use "$\mapsto$" or something similar, or write, for instance, $\frac{d}{dx} y^3 = 3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}$.)

Comment: using the product rule, i got (3x)'*y+3x*y'. what should it be then?

Comment: The third differential should be 3y+3xdy/dx. Then subtract it from the other two terms, and solve for dy/dx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating side by side $3y^{2}y'+3x^{2}=3y+3xy'$ where $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$. PS: Writing $x^{3}=3x^{2}$ to note that the derivative of $x^{3}$ is $3x^{2}$ is a little bit improper and can be misunderstood!.

Answer (score 0):

So...

$$y^3 + x^3 -3xy = 0$$

$$3y^2\dfrac{dy}{dx} + 3x^2 -3y -3x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$$

In the differentiation of the last  term, you used the product rule, which states that $(f(x)g(x))'=g'(x)f(x)+f'(x)g(x)$. If $f(x)=3x$ and $g(x)=y$, then $f'(x)=3$ and $g'(x)=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. This yields the above result.

Try solving from there, and things should go more smoothly!

Comment: Thanks, I found my mistake (3x)'=3, not x.